# How to build a language translator in Android?

Tags: android

I have set of words stored in string array. I need to pick a particular word and need to convert the word to my native language tamil. Example if the word is mobile it has to convert to my native language like how it happens from this link [English to Tamil](https://www.google.co.in/#safe=off&q=english+to+tamil+translation). How I can achieve it do I have to import google translator. Plz suggest me some good idea to do it. I cannot predict the words bez its users choice how do it  in android
.

Comment: you have strings.xml for that, isnt it?

Comment: It is like user would enter a string it will be stored in a string array and then the output would be in native lang. i cannot predict  the words. So how I can use strings.xml ?

Comment: You didnt say that the user would enter the words :), then you will need to use the translator

Comment: How to do that should I download any jar file, can u plz remove negative mark bez I would be blocked.

Comment: I didnt put you any negative mark :), check this link https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`Google Translate API`](https://cloud.google.com/translate/)

> Google Translate API provides a simple programmatic interface for
>   translating an arbitrary string into any supported language.

There is also a [`MyMemory API`](http://mymemory.translated.net/doc/spec.php)

> Our REST API has been designed to be as easy as possible to implement.
>   It is similar to the Google Translate API, extended with MyMemory
>   specific parameters and lets you search and contribute to MyMemory
>   archives.

There is also a [tutorial available](http://mycodeandlife.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/android-tutorials-language-translator-app/) on how to make a translator using [`Microsoft Translator`](https://code.google.com/p/microsoft-translator-java-api/):

> Provides a Java wrapper around the Microsoft Translator API aka Bing
>   Translator.